# How to create .msg file from mail object using c# without using interop

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a msg file from my mail message object in c#. I am referring the below document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82

Can someone help me by suggesting as how can do the same without using outlook interop and write the code purely in c#

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking so that your answer would be more likely to be answered than downvoted.

Comment: This article might help you https://support.microsoft.com/pt-pt/help/171907/info-save-message-to-msg-compound-file

Comment: You can't.  To send a mail message use SMTP class and use HTML.

Comment: I use msgKit and was able to save mail object as .msg file.